# use gtsummaty tbl_custom_summary function to do survey table

Tags: survey, gtsummary

[image]

This is what I am expecting for, certain type of stratification table to describe disease prevalence of certain subtype

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

set.seed(2023)
age<-runif(1000, min=18, max=97)
gender<-rbinom(1000, size=1, prob=0.46)
region<-rbinom(1000, size=1, prob=0.45)
smoking<-rbinom(1000, size=1, prob=0.31)
Mydata<-data.frame(age,gender,region,smoking)

Mydata$region<- factor(Mydata$region, levels=c(0,1),labels=c("City","Coungtryside"))
Mydata$gender<- factor(Mydata$gender, levels=c(0,1),labels=c("Female","Male"))
Mydata$smoking<- factor(Mydata$smoking, levels=c(0,1),labels=c("Nosmoking","Smoking"))
Mydata<-mutate(Mydata,age_group=ifelse(age<30,"18-",ifelse(age<40,"30-",ifelse(age<50,"40-      ",ifelse(age<60,"50-",ifelse(age<70,"60-",ifelse(age<80,"70-",ifelse(age<90,
                                                                                                                                                       "80-","90-")))))))) 

#Adding label from the very beginning
lookup    <- data.frame(code=c("age","age_group","gender","region","smoking"),
                    label = c("Age","Age group","sex","Region","Smoking"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(colnames(Mydata))) {
if(!is.na(match(colnames(Mydata), lookup$code)[i])) {
Hmisc::label(Mydata[[i]]) <- lookup$label[(match(colnames(Mydata), lookup$code))[i]]
 }
}

#Cross summary table
MydataCount<-Mydata %>% 
group_by(gender,age_group,region,smoking) %>%
summarise(freq=n())

#  gtsummarytable
proportion_summary_all <-
MydataCount %>%
as.data.frame() %>%
tbl_custom_summary(
include = c("age_group"),
by = "region",
stat_fns = ~ proportion_summary("smoking", "Smoking", weights = "freq"),
statistic = ~"{prop}% ({n}/{N}) ",
digits = ~ list(
  function(x) {
    style_percent(x, digits = 1)
  },
  0, 0, style_percent, style_percent
),
overall_row = TRUE,
overall_row_last = TRUE,
overall_row_label="Total"
 ) %>%
 add_overall() %>%
 bold_labels() %>%
 modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA) %>%
 modify_header(
label = "**Characteristics**",
stat_0 = "**Overall smoking**",
stat_1 = "**Countryside smoking**",
stat_2 = "**City smoking**"
)

proportion_summary_female <-
MydataCount %>% filter(gender=="Female") %>%
as.data.frame() %>%
tbl_custom_summary(
include = c("age_group"),
by = "region",
stat_fns = ~ proportion_summary("smoking", "Smoking", weights = "freq"),
statistic = ~"{prop}% ({n}/{N}) ",
digits = ~ list(
  function(x) {
    style_percent(x, digits = 1)
  },
  0, 0, style_percent, style_percent
),
overall_row = TRUE,
overall_row_last = TRUE,
overall_row_label="Total"
 ) %>%
add_overall() %>%
bold_labels() %>%
modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA) %>%
modify_header(
label = "**Characteristics**",
stat_0 = "**Overall smoking**",
stat_1 = "**Countryside smoking**",
stat_2 = "**City smoking**"
)

proportion_summary_male <-
MydataCount %>% filter(gender=="Male") %>%
as.data.frame() %>%
tbl_custom_summary(
include = c("age_group"),
by = "region",
stat_fns = ~ proportion_summary("smoking", "Smoking", weights = "freq"),
statistic = ~"{prop}% ({n}/{N}) ",
digits = ~ list(
  function(x) {
    style_percent(x, digits = 1)
  },
  0, 0, style_percent, style_percent
),
overall_row = TRUE,
overall_row_last = TRUE,
overall_row_label="Total"
) %>%
add_overall() %>%
bold_labels() %>%
modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA) %>%
modify_header(
label = "**Characteristics**",
stat_0 = "**Overall smoking**",
stat_1 = "**Countryside smoking**",
stat_2 = "**City smoking**"
)

tbl_surv_stack <- 
tbl_stack(
list(proportion_summary_male,proportion_summary_male, proportion_summary_female),
group_header = c("Male", "Female","Overall") 
)%>% as_gt() %>%
gt::tab_style(
style = gt::cell_text(weight = "bold"),
locations = gt::cells_row_groups(groups = everything())
)
```

I am using gtsummary  tbl_custom_summary function and i'am getting closed, but i can't move forward any more, it's too complicated! i need help!

Maybe not exactly the same, but the more similar, the better. Thank you very much~

[image]